# To Install Latin Modern Math font in OS X

Tags: macos, install, homebrew, font

I want to have the codes of the project [GUST](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) in my OS X. 
Franck indicates [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173141/13173) that the definite way is to download those fonts from there and install. 
However, I would like to find some packaged version because this is so standard tool. 
The fonts were removed from MacTeX 2015, while they were in MacTeX 2013. 
I could not find the fonts in homebrew.

### Test code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % also loads package fontspec
\usepackage{unicode-math} % if you also need maths
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
$\not\to$
\end{document}
```

giving *font-not-found* error. 
Disabling the line `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` gives the bad arrow which I do not want to have:

[image]

### Installing fonts manually

I downloaded the fonts [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download/lm2.004otf.zip) from the GUST project. 
I added the fonts to my system by opening *fontbook* and adding there the fonts directly. 
However, there is no *Latin Modern Math* in the package:

[image]

[image]

How can you install Modern Latin Math font in OS X?

Comment: The mactex-additions.pkg in the second link is now a broken link, not just from there but to original source too, although the [2012 package](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/mactex/2012/mactex-additions.pkg) still exists however not worth the 268.2 MB download when the fonts linked from the first link are 3.9 MB (OTF only).  I had no problem downloading and installing the fonts from [The Latin Modern collection v. 2.004—OTF files](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern/download/lm2.004otf.zip) using the OS X native Font Book to do it in one felled swoop.

Comment: Continued from first comment... I unzipped the archive and used Add Fonts... to select all 72 files and that was that.

Comment: I added the ways to illustrate that the package does not contain *Latin Modern Math* font. Most others however. Can you replicate?

Comment: Can't you get it at  http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download/index_html

Comment: @TomGewecke I did it but it did not solve the misaligned line of the arrow. I do not understand what causes it, since the font should solve the problem.

Comment: What is the Unicode number of that arrow character?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've also noticed The Latin Modern fonts are not installed to OS X with the MacTeX2015 distibution.

The LM fonts (also the math font) are installed in the tex distribution under: 
`/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm`
and `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math`

To use these font's throughout OS X there is no need to reinstall them, you can link these fonts to your `Fonts` in OS X as follows:

```
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/ '/Library/Fonts/Latin Modern'
ln -s /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/ '/Library/Fonts/Latin Modern Math'
```

*Note: This was inspired by the comments on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173141/how-to-add-the-mactex-subpackage-latin-modern-fonts-to-a-basictex-installation) question.*

Comment: Just realised it might be even better to link them to your user fonts in `~/Library/Fonts`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is logical and better than new installation.

Comment: Or, import the font from the texlive location into Font Book: Click on the '+' symbol (or menu File > Add Fonts... or shortcut &#8984;-O) and then click SHIFT-CMD-G (Go to Folder) in the file selection dialog to get a text field where you can enter `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/` and then select both, `lm` and `lm-math` folders.

Comment: N.B. this continues to work with TexLive 2022